# jQuery popup min and max width/height

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

If I set the popup minWidth to 440 px (example), will the width automatically grow with the content? Do I have to write extra code to make it dynamically growing?

```
dialogDiv.dialog({
        title: "Confirm Delete",
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        minWidth: 440,
        minHeight:220,
```

Comment: What popup? You must explain it to allow us to know the functionality. Share your code. Adding to this, `min-width` is a property in css that allow you to make what you need, set the minimum width to start and grow with the content. You can set a `max-width` to control the opposite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Min-width simply specifies the smallest width you'd like an element to be.  You're saying 'I don't care how big this element is, just don't let it be smaller than 440px'.  So yes, as long as no other styles get in the way, it should expand to fit the content.  Check out w3c for an example you can play with and more info: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp